# Correct usage of auxiliary verbs in a complex sentences with multiple tenses

Tags: grammar

Please correct me if it is wrong...,

"Do you know when our next class ***is starting***  ?"

```
                        or
```

"Do you know when our next class ***starts***?"

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

Being very careful, I'd recommend

> Do you know when our next class starts

because starting is not a process that takes place throughout an interval and so will seldom if ever **strictly** warrant a progressive tense.

In actual practice, however, very few people are that exact in their language, and you will hear both forms used by well educated native speakers interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks Jeff...!